# Why same alpha map is not working for different material?

Tags: transparency

I am using a texture for cutout of footprints. As u can see in the picture, the magenta one's are cutout perfectly, but the violet one's are not working.

[image: enter image description here 2]

both objects are using similar materia

l[image: material for magenta]
[image: material for violet]

Still it is working with only one(magenta). I'm having this problem in Eevee render. Cycles is perfectly fine but i need eevee for view port shading and this just looks bad.

Comment: Make sure the Blend Mode of the material is not set to _Opaque_. Alpha-blend usually works well.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!! Thank you so much.